# Strange squeaking sound from Asus K52F laptop

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, ubuntu-14.04, asus-laptop

About an year ago a strange sound started to appear from a laptop when it is turned on. I have no idea what that sound causes but on the Internet there are similar posts. I searched for a solution but did not found any acceptable. Currently I am using Ubuntu 14.04 OS while those solutions (modifying something about idle power in registry) required a Windows OS. I am attaching a photo in which I have marked the area where the sound is coming from. How to solve this squeaking sound problem?

Laptop model: Asus K52F (made in 2010).

[image]

Comment: I am going to guess its your Wireless card interferring with your soundcard.  Since the part you highlighted, is exactly that, your wireless card.

Comment: I have tried to unplug Wireless card (removed it from slot) but still the squeaking sound was coming from somewhere near there.

Comment: If its not interference then its one of your mechanical devices.

Comment: Those partially-hidden grey components appear to be inductors. Sometimes they whine: [Coil whine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coil_noise). There is not really much you can do about it, assuming you cannot translate the Windows version of the fix to Ubuntu, other than selling the laptop to someone with less sensitive hearing than yours.

Comment: I believe that may be it. Also that sounds sometimes appears to be strong sometimes weak or even disappears for a few minutes. When it is squeaking there are pauses for around 2 seconds but this happens pretty rare.

Comment: You never really asked a question...

Comment: That is obvious that normally there should not be a squeaking sound coming from an electronic device.

Comment: What is the Windows version of the fix?

Comment: From [Fix the Asus Laptop High Pitched Noise Problem](http://asusnoise.blogspot.co.uk/), it appears that [cpupower  idle-set](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man1/cpupower-idle-set.1.html) might help. Note that disabling sleep states will make the battery run down more quickly, although that will probably be less annoying than the noise.

Comment: The obvious solution would be fine somebody to remove and replace the inductors with those of better quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AndrewMorton Thank you, I have disabled 3 and 4 idle states and everything sorted out. If anyone is going to need this solution, I have Intel i3-350M processor and Asus HM55 mobile chipset. By turning two idle states off I have noticed shorter battery life (by 10-30 minutes) but by leaving other three (there's 5 overall) it's pretty decent. Solution was: sudo cpupower idle-set -d 3 && sudo cpupower idle-set -d 4